# How to build standalone executable cucumber jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, maven-3

I want to create a executable jar file so anyone can run it from their computer with least install require components.

I found several tutorial but none of them a work.

When I execute jar file I've built they are return error like:
Error: Could not find or load main class fully.qualified.MainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fully.qualified.MainClass

OR like this:
Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

My project run from Intellij with no problem.

Here my project structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcQzf.png

And my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberSelenium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cucumber.version>7.6.0</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.8.0</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.2.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <apache.common.version>2.4</apache.common.version>
        <projectlombok.version>1.18.24</projectlombok.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit Platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web Driver Manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.common.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                    <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>io.cucumber.core.cli.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've run mvn clean compile assembly:single, it's output a CucumberSelenium-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar file, but it wont runs.

Comment: "could not find or load main class fully.qualified.MainClass": the bundled jar may doesn't include this class for some reason, unzip the jar can see if it contain that class; "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.cli.Main": it seems that jar is not a flat jar which doesn't include all libraries like cucumber; "I've run mvn clean compile assembly:single, it's output a CucumberSelenium-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar file, but it won't runs.": what's the error in this case?

Comment: If the missing class is in cucumber-java try making that compile scope instead of test scope.

Comment: thanks @tgdavies now the main class problem solved but the new problem is no features found at classpath

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar issue and, despite trying the ubiquitous

```
java -cp . org.example.Main
```

(while on current directory being where the Main.class is), I kept getting this dreaded

> "Error: Could not find or load main class"

I eventually resorted to **comparing** the actual command with parameters invoked by IntelliJ (on IntelliJ IDEA's debug log) with mine, and discovered that the following solves the issue:

```
java -cp C:\Users\WebViwer\IdeaProjects\MyProj\target\classes org.example.Main
```

I am guessing that once the fully qualified class name is specified, the current directory (where the class resides) is no longer valid as a classpath: Only the top level `classes` directory should be specified (in this `org.example`, 2 levels up).

Answer (score 0):

You have a a few problems going on.

1. The `maven-assembly-plugin` should not be a in the `dependencies` section. It is not a dependency used by the runtime code of your project.
2. Your step definitions, feature files and glue code located in `src/test` are not included in the jar file build by the assembly plugin.
3. Your `test` scoped dependencies will also not be included by the assembly plugin either.
4. You must configure the `containerDescriptorHandler` of the assembly plugin with `metaInf-services` or the plugin will not merge files in `META-INF/services` correctly.

You can verify most of these by opening the generated jar file (it's a `.zip` file in disguise).

> My project run from Intellij with no problem.

When running tests in Intelij you are using the `test` scope, the jar file only includes `runtime` scoped code.

For a more comparable test you must create a new run configuration that invokes the main method.

> I found several tutorial but none of them a work.

It appears that you are relatively new to Java and Maven. It would be prudent to follow a proper course first rather than tutorials. You are missing fundamental knowledge that is generally not taught in tutorials.

> I want to create a executable jar file so anyone can run it from their computer with least install require components.

It's also prudent to consider why you are doing this.

Tests will typically change as quickly as the source code they are testing does. Manually distribution of jar files won't keep up with this.

This means it's generally better to integrate the tests and the test source code into the automated build pipeline of the project they test.

This also means that you don't need to distribute your tests as a jar. Rather you should expect (and possibly train) people to use Maven, GIT and Java.